# jquery slider vertical

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vpH8r/2/

I have created a jfiddle above with my attempt to get vertical sliding working.

The current issues are the slider tab doesn't move and it doesn't appear the cleanly slide from the top to the bottom.

Note: I'm using:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js

and

jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js

which I couldn't seem to enable together in jfiddle (maybe there is a way to do this - I wasn't sure)  - currently the demo using older versions of jquery and jquery-ui.

thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Here it is fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/vpH8r/13/

Here's what you needed to do:

1. You had both `top:` and `bottom:` set, and top tends to get priority, whereas if you have both, only `top:` goes into effect no matter the order. by removing top in your css it now slides, but it also makes it start at the bottom which is why you need the next part
2. the `value:` option in the jquery slider function sets the starting position to 100% (from the bottom) which makes it start nicely at the top.

In order to get it to align in the middle you need to do the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -.6em;  /* half the width of the element */
</style>
```